# Proper way of converting a negative JOOQ YearToSecond object into milliseconds

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

When loading a negative `Interval` from a Postgresql database and converting it to milliseconds it's sign is ignored and I get a positive value.
I am converting the `YearToSecond` with `doubleValue()`.

```
@Test
void testYearToSecondNegativeInterval()
{
  assertThat(YearToSecond.valueOf(2).doubleValue()).isEqualTo(2);
  assertThat(YearToSecond.valueOf(-2).doubleValue()).isEqualTo(-2);

  YearToSecond minus9802 = YearToSecond.valueOf("-0-0 +0 00:00:09.082000000");
  assertThat(minus9802.doubleValue()).isEqualTo(-9802);
}
```

This unit test fails with:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <9082.0>
to be equal to:
 <-9802.0>
but was not.
```

I got the `String` representation (`-0-0 +0 00:00:09.082000000`) from a debugging session.
When querying the same value is shown as `-00:00:09.082` with `intervalstyle = 'sql_standard'` and  `PT-9.082S` with `intervalstyle = 'iso_8601'`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is directly fetching the value as milliseconds:

```
create.select(DSL.extract(TABLE.COLUMN, DatePart.EPOCH)
                 .mul(1000)
                 .cast(Integer.class))
      .from(COLUMN)
```

But this means additional work because an additional field must be fetched compared to converting the `YearToSecond`.